# Accordion menu in bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/luismruiz/YRVev/). Is there any option that I can close sub menu when I click outside the div?

```
      <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
               <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#leftMenu" href="#collapseTwo">
                   <i class="icon-th"></i> Layout
                </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
               <div class="accordion-inner">
                   <ul>
                      <li>This is one</li>
                      <li>This is two</li>
                      <li>This is Three</li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

I'm using bootstrap 3.

Comment: If you see the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) you can use the `.collapse('hide')` method for closing. Check this [link](http://www.bootply.com/63158).

Comment: thx,yes i miss that part but i'm looking for a way without writing custom javascript and i'm using angularJs

Comment: You have to write a custom script here as you want a working that the collapse doesn't provide.

Comment: ok.many thanks, I'll give you a write answer if you put your answer in answer section :)

Comment: Updated the answer with comments inside the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) you can use the `.collapse('hide')` method for closing.

> .collapse('hide')
>
> Hides a collapsible element.

Update:

On document click you will have to check if the clicked element is outside.

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    // here you can change document to any div id 

    if (!$(e.target).closest('#leftMenu').hasClass('accordion')) { // checking if clicked element is outside `accordion` then only collapse

        $('.in').collapse('hide'); // .in as we need to collapse only the expanded section
    }
});
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/YRVev/1859/)